# Odd results from shaders used to pre-process spring physics simulation

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, physics

I'm doing a spring physics simulation using 2D samplers to house and pre-process some position data in a fragment shader, and getting very odd results. If I start with 16 individually located springs (a point at the end of an invisible spring originating from an invisible anchor), the visualization ends up with eight pairs, each pair hanging from the same spring anchor point. However, if I simply run the visualization to place the points using only the `tOffsets` values, all the information to calculate each of the anchor points is there and displays correctly (though no physics, of course). It's once I add back in the spring physics that I end up with pairs again. Also, from watching the visualization, I can tell that the pairs' anchor points values are none of the original 16 anchor point values. Any idea what's going on here? (See both the fiddle and the starred inline comments below.)

(three.js v 80)

**See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/og075w2x/) using v79 here.**

```
uniform sampler2D tPositions;
uniform sampler2D tOffsets;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {

    float damping = 0.98;

    vec4 nowPos = texture2D( tPositions, vUv ).xyzw;
    vec4 offsets = texture2D( tOffsets, vUv ).xyzw;
    vec2 velocity = vec2(nowPos.z, nowPos.w);


    vec2 anchor = vec2( offsets.x, 130.0 );

    // Newton's law: F = M * A
    float mass = 24.0;
    vec2 acceleration = vec2(0.0, 0.0);

    // 1. apply gravity's force: **this works fine
    vec2 gravity = vec2(0.0, 2.0);
    gravity /= mass;
    acceleration += gravity;

    // 2. apply the spring force ** something goes wrong once I add the spring physics - the springs display in pairs
    float restLength = length(yAnchor - offsets.y);
    float springConstant = 0.2;

    // Vector pointing from anchor to point position
    vec2 springForce = vec2(nowPos.x - anchor.x, nowPos.y - anchor.y);
    // length of the vector
    float distance = length( springForce );
    // stretch is the difference between the current distance and restLength
    float stretch =  distance - restLength;

    // Calculate springForce according to Hooke's Law
    springForce = normalize( springForce );
    springForce *= (1.0 * springConstant * stretch);

    springForce /= mass;
    acceleration += springForce; // ** If I comment out this line, all points display where expected, and fall according to gravity. If I add it it back in the springs work properly but display in 8 pairs as opposed to 16 independent locations

    velocity += acceleration;
    velocity *= damping;

    vec2 newPosition = vec2(nowPos.x - velocity.x, nowPos.y - velocity.y);     

    // Write new position out to texture for the next shader
    gl_FragColor = vec4(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, velocity.x, velocity.y); // **the pair problem shows up with this line active

    // sanity checks with comments:
    // gl_FragColor = vec4(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, 0.0, 0.0); // **the pair problem also shows up in this case
    // gl_FragColor = vec4( offsets.x, offsets.y, velocity ); // **all points display in the correct position, though no physics
    // gl_FragColor = vec4(nowPos.x, nowPos.y, 0.0, 0.0); // **all points display in the correct position, though no physics
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Could the problem be with the number of values (rgba, xzyw) agreeing between all of the pieces of my program? I've specified rgba values wherever I can think to, but perhaps I've missed somewhere. Here is a snippet from my javascript:

```
if ( ! renderer.context.getExtension( 'OES_texture_float' ) ) {
        alert( 'OES_texture_float is not :(' );
}

var width = 4, height = 4; 
particles = width * height;

// Start creation of DataTexture
var positions = new Float32Array( particles * 4 );
var offsets = new Float32Array( particles * 4 );

// hardcoded dummy values for the sake of debugging:
var somePositions = [10.885510444641113, -6.274578094482422, 0, 0, -10.12020206451416, 0.8196354508399963, 0, 0, 35.518341064453125, -5.810637474060059, 0, 0, 3.7696402072906494, -3.118760347366333, 0, 0, 9.090447425842285, -7.851400375366211, 0, 0, -32.53229522705078, -26.4628849029541, 0, 0, 32.3623046875, 22.746187210083008, 0, 0, 7.844726085662842, -15.305091857910156, 0, 0, -32.65345001220703, 22.251712799072266, 0, 0, -25.811357498168945, 32.4153938293457, 0, 0, -28.263731002807617, -31.015430450439453, 0, 0, 2.0903847217559814, 1.7632032632827759, 0, 0, -4.471604347229004, 8.995194435119629, 0, 0, -12.317420959472656, 12.19576358795166, 0, 0, 36.77312469482422, -14.580523490905762, 0, 0, 36.447078704833984, -16.085195541381836, 0, 0];

for ( var i = 0, i4 = 0; i < particles; i ++, i4 +=4 ) {

    positions[ i4 + 0 ] = somePositions[ i4 + 0 ]; // x
    positions[ i4 + 1 ] = somePositions[ i4 + 1 ]; // y
    positions[ i4 + 2 ] = 0.0; // velocity
    positions[ i4 + 3 ] = 0.0; // velocity

    offsets[ i4 + 0 ] = positions[ i4 + 0 ];// - gridPositions[ i4 + 0 ]; // width offset
    offsets[ i4 + 1 ] = positions[ i4 + 1 ];// - gridPositions[ i4 + 1 ]; // height offset
    offsets[ i4 + 2 ] = 0; // not used
    offsets[ i4 + 3 ] = 0; // not used

}

positionsTexture = new THREE.DataTexture( positions, width, height, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.FloatType );
positionsTexture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
positionsTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
positionsTexture.needsUpdate = true;

offsetsTexture = new THREE.DataTexture( offsets, width, height, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.FloatType );
offsetsTexture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
offsetsTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
offsetsTexture.needsUpdate = true;

rtTexturePos = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, {
    wrapS:THREE.RepeatWrapping,
    wrapT:THREE.RepeatWrapping,
    minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    type:THREE.FloatType,
    stencilBuffer: false
});

rtTexturePos2 = rtTexturePos.clone();

simulationShader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        tPositions: { type: "t", value: positionsTexture },
        tOffsets: { type: "t", value: offsetsTexture },
    },
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('texture_vertex_simulation_shader').textContent,
        fragmentShader:  document.getElementById('texture_fragment_simulation_shader').textContent
});

fboParticles = new THREE.FBOUtils( width, renderer, simulationShader );
fboParticles.renderToTexture(rtTexturePos, rtTexturePos2);

fboParticles.in = rtTexturePos;
fboParticles.out = rtTexturePos2;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Perhaps the problem has to do with how the texels are being read from these textures? Somehow it may be reading between two texels, and so coming up with an averaged position shared by two springs? Is this possible? If so, where would I look to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never discovered the problem with the fiddle in my question above; however, I did eventually find the newer version of the THREE.FBOUtils script I was using above - it is now called [THREE.GPUComputationRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cefe993143146ea2479fdbf3bfcf51ee1c856d83/examples/js/GPUComputationRenderer.js). After implementing it, my script finally worked!

For those who find themselves trying trying so solve a similar problem, here is the **new and improved [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/omuqc1ws/)** using the GPUComputationRenderer in place of the old FBOUtils.

Here, from the script documentation, is a basic use case of GPUComputationRenderer:

```
//Initialization...

// Create computation renderer
var gpuCompute = new GPUComputationRenderer( 1024, 1024, renderer );

// Create initial state float textures
var pos0 = gpuCompute.createTexture();
var vel0 = gpuCompute.createTexture();
// and fill in here the texture data...

// Add texture variables
var velVar = gpuCompute.addVariable( "textureVelocity", fragmentShaderVel, pos0 );
var posVar = gpuCompute.addVariable( "texturePosition", fragmentShaderPos, vel0 );

// Add variable dependencies
gpuCompute.setVariableDependencies( velVar, [ velVar, posVar ] );
gpuCompute.setVariableDependencies( posVar, [ velVar, posVar ] );

// Add custom uniforms
velVar.material.uniforms.time = { value: 0.0 };

// Check for completeness
var error = gpuCompute.init();
if ( error !== null ) {
   console.error( error );
}

// In each frame...

// Compute!
gpuCompute.compute();

// Update texture uniforms in your visualization materials with the gpu renderer output
myMaterial.uniforms.myTexture.value = gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( posVar ).texture;

// Do your rendering
renderer.render( myScene, myCamera );
```